# MAUI Picker style in Windows Platforms

Tags: c#, .net, maui

I am trying to change the default style of the Picker control in MAUI but cannot find a solution.
I would first like to remove this highlighted rectangle in the picture:

[image: Maui Picker]

I had the same problem with Entries but solved it by inserting these lines of code in `Platforms/Windows/App.xaml`

```
        <maui:MauiWinUIApplication.Resources>
          <Thickness x:Key="TextControlBorderThemeThickness">0</Thickness>
          <Thickness x:Key="TextControlBorderThemeThicknessFocused">0</Thickness>
        </maui:MauiWinUIApplication.Resources>
```

For pickers (or ComboBoxes) I cannot find anything like this to override, does anyone have any ideas?

Many thanks

Comment: You'll probably need to do this using [handlers and mappings](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/maui/user-interface/handlers/customize).

Comment: Thanks @Julian, but I solved it another way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change the default style of the [Picker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/picker) in MAUI, you need to specify the correspondent `x:Key` of the [ComboBox](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/blob/main/dev/ComboBox/ComboBox_themeresources.xaml) and the [Picker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/picker) will automatically consume the `x:Key` when running the MAUI app.

`ComboBoxItemPillFillBrush` is used to change the `ItemPillFill` of the selected items in Picker,

```
<maui:MauiWinUIApplication.Resources> 

      <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBoxItemPillFillBrush" Color="#00FFFFFF" />
     

</maui:MauiWinUIApplication.Resources>
```

If you want to custom more styles of the [Picker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/picker), you can refer to https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/blob/main/dev/ComboBox/ComboBox_themeresources.xaml.

Hope that helps!

Below are Yoji's edit:
**EDIT:**

I was not able to remove the rectangle permanently but I used a workaround:

```
  <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBoxItemPillFillBrush" Color="#00FFFFFF"/>
```

Doing so overrides the colour of the selected item and the rectangle by putting them at the same color so as to hide it!

Comment: Hi Alexandar, thank you for your reply, but it still does not correspond to what I wanted to change.
I tried to insert the code you provided but the border that changes is that of the entire popup containing the elements, not the single rectangle next to each selected element

Comment: Hi Yoji, No problem. The key that you want to remove the highlighted rectangle should exist in this [ComboBox_themeresources.xaml](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/blob/main/dev/ComboBox/ComboBox_themeresources.xaml). Since there're many keys, you may need to find it by yourself. At least we are in the right direction!

Comment: @Yoji Thanks for your commitment. I just figured out that change the `Colour` of `ComboBoxItemPillFillBrush` to `Color="#00FFFFFF"` will become transparent and remove the highlighter.

Comment: Hi Alexandar. Yes, I have already used this workaround to hide e.g. the glyph of the datePicker control! Putting the colour to Transparent resulted in it being hidden. The link you posted was very useful indeed, thanks

Comment: Don't mention it. Happy coding!

Comment: I have the same issue on a Flyout Menu item, but I can't find the property to set the color. Do you have any idea ?

Comment: @RomEh You can also set it in `Platforms/Windows/App.xaml` using a different property.

Comment: I had no clues to find the right property, but got a repsonse : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78011550/set-the-color-of-vertical-bar-in-a-flyour-menu-item/78018457#78018457. If you have resources to find that kind of property, it would be great. Thank you for your help

Comment: @RomEh you can find resources here, but you have to find the right file. Normally under "CommonStyles" directory you can find what you search.
https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/tree/winui2/main/dev