# Set the color of vertical bar in a Flyour menu item

Tags: maui, maui-windows, .net-maui.shell

In my .NET MAUI 8.0 app, I can't find the property to set the colour of the vertical bar in the shell flyout menu item as shown in the picture below. The image is from a sample MAUI app ([ShellFlyoutSample](https://github.com/dotnet/maui-samples/tree/main/8.0/Navigation/ShellFlyoutSample)), on Windows.

[image]

On Andrdoid, there is not such vertical bar in the shell flyout menu.

What is the property linked to this feature ?

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77195931/maui-picker-style-in-windows-platforms) looks similar, but I can't find a equivalent property for the Shell Flyout Menu Item. Have you already done this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set its color in the **Platforms/Windows/App.xaml**:

```
<maui:MauiWinUIApplication
    x:Class="ShellFlyoutSample.WinUI.App"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:maui="using:Microsoft.Maui"
    xmlns:local="using:MauiAppTst.WinUI">

    <maui:MauiWinUIApplication.Resources>
        <StaticResource x:Key="NavigationViewSelectionIndicatorForeground" ResourceKey="SystemControlForegroundAccentBrush" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SystemControlForegroundAccentBrush"  Color="Red" />
        // you can set the other color such as blue/transparent
    </maui:MauiWinUIApplication.Resources>
</maui:MauiWinUIApplication>
```